# Why does making this variable nullable produce a linting error in VSCode?

Tags: typescript

The two statements below seem to be equivalent to me, but one of them triggers a linting warning from TSLint in VSCode. Why?

```
const task: Task | undefined = this.tasksQuery.getEntity('15')
// passes linting with no problems

const task?: Task = this.tasksQuery.getEntity('15')
// Triggers the linting error: "Multiple variable declarations 
// in the same statement are forbidden (one-variable-per-declaration)"
```

Comment: You can't have an optional const (before the colon you're in JS, **not** TS, land); you're effectively writing a [conditional expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Variable declarations cannot have question tokens so the second line is invalid in any case.

Comment: In fact per https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGEDWB+AXDAKopMC8cAFgJYQB0CyEAigK4CmATgJ5kDm9UAomFMVMwAUAcgCMAVmEBKAFBA it looks like the compiler's best guess is `const task, Task = this.tasksQuery.getEntity('15');`, hence the warning.

Comment: ahh ok - so the ? operator can only be used for nullable parameters, not for nullable variables...

Comment: ?: optional operator can be used ONLY inside type declaration.
What mean const task?: Task
You can also define task variable as let: Taks;